# Adaptar dimensiones de una img a un contenedor

Tags: html5, css3

Buen día, el problema que tengo es que quiero que una imagen tome las dimensiones de un contenedor sin perder calidad y que se vea completa. Esta es la imagen original:

[image]

Y este es el codigo:

```
<section class="hero">
    <div class="contenido-hero">
        <h2 class="titulo">Diseño y Desarrollo Web <span>Freelancer</span></h2>

        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-map-pin" width="88" height="88" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#ffc107" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
            <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
            <circle cx="12" cy="11" r="3" />
            <path d="M17.657 16.657l-4.243 4.243a2 2 0 0 1 -2.827 0l-4.244 -4.243a8 8 0 1 1 11.314 0z" />
          </svg>
        <p>Santa fe, Rafaela </p>

        <a href="#">Contactar</a>
    </div>

</section>

.hero
    {
        background-image: url(../img/heroo.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow Naik!, para que sea más fácil ayudarte agrega el código como texto y no una imagen. Puedes leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: El código debe ir en formato texto y no en imagen, por favor edita tu pregunta haciendo clic en [edit]. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Si el navegador tiene que amopliar una imagen va a perder calidad si o si (salvo las SVG).
**Solución**: emplea una imagen suficientemente grande como para que el navegador no tenga que ampliarla sino reducirla de tamaño para ajustarla al contenedor.
Lo que has usado para **background-size: cover** es correcto si quieres que la imagen de fondo **cubra todo el contenedor** donde está situada. Si es necesario reducirá y recortará lo que sobre.
La otra opción para **background-size: contanin** puedes usara la asegurarte de que **se ve toda la imagen**.
Y la última opción sería poner a la imagen un style  con width=100%, con lo que la imagen ocupará el ancho total del contenedor y el alto correspondiente. Pero esto creo que no es lo que buscas.

Answer (score 0):

Con el código anterior se ve así:

.hero
{

```
 background-image: url(../img/heroo.jpg);
    
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    
 background-size: cover;
```

}
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y se ve así con el background-size: contain;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque le aplique un width de 100% se ve igual y ya probé con otras imágenes, cambiarle las dimensiones pero se termina viendo mal la imagen. Yo quisiera que se viera toda la imagen completa cuando la estiro a lo ancho y largo